# How to implement Pusher with Typescript in Node.JS server

Tags: node.js, typescript, pusher

i got problem with Pusher when integrating with typescript, ts says that 
This expression is not constructable.
  Type 'typeof Pusher' has no construct signatures

[image: as shown]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! To improve your experience, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question. You should also take a look at the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To lean more about how Stack Overflow works, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 3):

One suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57079925) didn't work for me, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61595910) one did.

Instead of

```
new Pusher(
```

use

```
new Pusher.default(
```